# SQL Server - Select column where range is given in the column description

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ID  Description

51  SY10K40F

18  SY20K40F

12  SY30K40F

28  SY40K40F

34  SY100K40H

35  SY240K40H

36  SY300K40H
```

I have to select only those id for which description range is `10K to 40K`.

Note - Id is primary key and from description we are getting 10k,20k etc.

Comment: Nice question! Substring wouldn't do, since the value after SY can be 2-3 characters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've got it right:

```
WHERE 
CAST(SUBSTRING(Description,3,CHARINDEX('K',Description)-3) AS INT)
BETWEEN 10 and 40
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0663/6)</kbd>

Assuming your comment to this answer the first position isn't fixed so in this case you should use [PATINDEX()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function in MSSQL:

```
WHERE 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Description,
                    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Description), 
                    PATINDEX('%[0-9]K%',Description)-
                    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Description)+1)
         AS INT)
      BETWEEN 10 and 40
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80bc6/10)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for your solution. Now i have the scenario given below.

51  SY10K40F

18  SYA20K40F

12  SY30K40F

28  SYAB40K40F

34  SYA100K40H

35  SYAB240K40H

36  SYA300K40H

The thing is occurrence of 10k 20k etc are not fixed. May be it can come in 3rd place may be in 5th place in the description. In this scenario what is the solution for the same problem.

Comment: @Ankit I've updated the answer to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution is as below,

```
Select 
  * 
FROM 
  Table1 
WHERE
  Description like '__10K%'
OR
  Description like '__20K%'
OR
  Description like '__30K%'
OR
  Description like '__40K%';
```

working demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0e49/3

Comment: it is not simple sol..what if range is increased from 10k to 40000k you need to hard code it? and it doesnt list you if any thing like `sy11k40F` is present

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT t.Id,
       t.desp,
from
(
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Description] as desp
      ,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([Description],3,LEN([Description])),0, CHARINDEX('K',SUBSTRING([Description],3,LEN([Description])),0)) as rag      
  FROM [dbo].[testRange]
)t
where CONVERT(INT,t.rag) > 20 AND CONVERT(INT,t.rag) < 40
```